# windows xp not present at boot menu after linux mint installation

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot, linux-mint

I have an old pc with windows xp and i installed in a different partition linux mint 15,and when i turn it on it doesnt give me the option to choose which OS i want  and goes directly into Mint,  i have already tried this solution but it hasn.t fix my problem http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/245. this is what i get from terminal 
sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for vaios: 
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
  No volume groups found
done
any help would really help! :-)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't install over your Windows installation?

Comment: yes because i can still see my other partition when i open my computer

Answer (score 0):

When you install Linux along with windows you will able to log into windows using the grub boot loader. it wit will list the available OS.
If you are not viewing the windows then you had made something wrong with the drive that contains windows.
if you are able to see the contents of the drive containing the windows installation then edit boot.ini file.

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer. What edit would need to be done to the boot.ini file?